Comfyui, how to create a custom node that dynamically updates the sub-options based on the selected main option
This custom node have a first option (main) to select the type of other options. I can´t get the condition to act as a selector to show a serie of options or the other.
`@classmethod
def INPUT_TYPES(s):
    return {
        "required": {
            "mode": (["text", "file"],)
            ...
            IF mode == "text":
               "text_content": ("STRING", {
                "multiline": False,
                "default": "Text",
            })
            ELSE:
               "file_path": ("STRING", {
                "multiline": False,
                "default": "/",
            })


        },
    }`

i also can´t find an existing custom node that offers this type of selection and auto-update... anyone?
i tried various options, including suggestions from Perpexity, without success.
